# Prove that $\mathcal{O}_K$ for $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is euclidean

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-domain

I'm having trouble with this question concerning the ring of integers of a real quadratic field:
[image]

I know that if we can prove that the ring is euclidean then every ideal is principal, and thus $C(\mathcal{O}_K) \simeq 1$.

I just don't get what the question means when it says "the absolute value of the norm fuction" and how can this help the proof that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is euclidean

Comment: to show a ring is Euclidean, you need a "valuation function", and they're suggesting $\nu:a+b\sqrt3\mapsto |a^2-3b^2|$

Comment: Thank you. I will try this tomorrow and get back to this thread later.